# VSCode - toggling navigation in Zen mode (Linux Ubuntu)

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I am in Zen mode or full-screen mode and press the Alt key, the top of navigation toggling. Is there some chance to remove this behavior? Because I am using Alt key for jumping between words and the navigation toggling and it is really not comfortable. Thank you

I mean this top window navigation
[image]

Comment: Try disabling the `Menu Bar Mnemonics` setting.

Comment: I am disable this setting in my settings "window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false but when I press only the Alt keyboard the top menu is triggered...